# install docker on debian - 'overlay' is not supported over overlayfs

Tags: docker, debian

I created a docker image for my build pipeline and I am trying to run `docker build -t someTag .`

However, I am getting this error.

```
DEBU[0000] Listener created for HTTP on unix (/var/run/docker.sock)
INFO[0000] libcontainerd: new containerd process, pid: 1026
DEBU[0000] Permission denied writing "-500" to /proc/1026/oom_score_adj
DEBU[0000] containerd: grpc api on /var/run/docker/libcontainerd/docker-containerd.sock
DEBU[0000] containerd: read past events                  count=0
DEBU[0000] containerd: supervisor running                cpus=2 memory=976 runtime=docker-runc runtimeArgs=[] stateDir="/var/run/docker/libcontainerd/containerd"
DEBU[0000] libcontainerd: containerd health check returned error: rpc error: code = 14 desc = grpc: the connection is unavailable
DEBU[0001] Permission denied writing "-500" to /proc/self/oom_score_adj
DEBU[0001] Using default logging driver json-file
DEBU[0001] Golang's threads limit set to 6840
DEBU[0001] [zfs] zfs command is not available: exec: "zfs": executable file not found in $PATH
ERRO[0001] 'overlay' is not supported over overlayfs
DEBU[0001] Using graph driver vfs
DEBU[0001] Max Concurrent Downloads: 3
DEBU[0001] Max Concurrent Uploads: 5
INFO[0001] Graph migration to content-addressability took 0.00 seconds
INFO[0001] Loading containers: start.
DEBU[0001] Option Experimental: false
DEBU[0001] Option DefaultDriver: bridge
DEBU[0001] Option DefaultNetwork: bridge
WARN[0001] Running modprobe bridge br_netfilter failed with message: , error: exec: "modprobe": executable file not found in $PATH
WARN[0001] Running modprobe nf_nat failed with message: ``, error: exec: "modprobe": executable file not found in $PATH
WARN[0001] Running modprobe xt_conntrack failed with message: ``, error: exec: "modprobe": executable file not found in $PATH
DEBU[0001] Fail to initialize firewalld: Failed to connect to D-Bus system bus: dial unix /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: connect: no such file or directory, using raw iptables instead
DEBU[0001] /usr/sbin/iptables, [-t nat -D PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER]
DEBU[0001] /usr/sbin/iptables, [-t nat -D OUTPUT -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL ! --dst 127.0.0.0/8 -j DOCKER]
DEBU[0001] /usr/sbin/iptables, [-t nat -D OUTPUT -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER]
DEBU[0001] /usr/sbin/iptables, [-t nat -D PREROUTING]
DEBU[0001] /usr/sbin/iptables, [-t nat -D OUTPUT]
DEBU[0001] /usr/sbin/iptables, [-t nat -F DOCKER]
DEBU[0001] /usr/sbin/iptables, [-t nat -X DOCKER]
DEBU[0001] /usr/sbin/iptables, [-t filter -F DOCKER]
DEBU[0001] /usr/sbin/iptables, [-t filter -X DOCKER]
DEBU[0001] /usr/sbin/iptables, [-t filter -F DOCKER-ISOLATION]
DEBU[0001] /usr/sbin/iptables, [-t filter -X DOCKER-ISOLATION]
DEBU[0001] /usr/sbin/iptables, [-t nat -n -L DOCKER]
DEBU[0001] /usr/sbin/iptables, [-t nat -N DOCKER]
DEBU[0001] start clean shutdown of all containers with a 15 seconds timeout...
DEBU[0001] Cleaning up old mountid : start.
DEBU[0001] Cleaning up old mountid : done.
```

Here is the info of my `Dockerfile` that is installing docker. I found these steps [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/docker-ce/debian/#install-from-a-package).

```
FROM debian:latest

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV JENKINS_HOME /var/jenkins_home

USER root

WORKDIR $JENKINS_HOME

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install \
    apt-transport-https \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    gnupg2 \
    software-properties-common -y
RUN curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | apt-key add -
RUN apt-get install -y iptables
RUN wget https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/dists/jessie/pool/stable/amd64/docker-ce_17.06.0~ce-0~debian_amd64.deb
RUN dpkg -i docker-ce_17.06.0~ce-0~debian_amd64.deb
```

What I have tried:

I have tried starting [dockerd](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/#start-the-daemon-using-operating-system-utilities). 
From my best guess, it looks like I need `dockerd` to start.

```
root@90302deb48a0:/var/jenkins_home# ps -ef | grep docker
root          6      1  0 14:47 ?        00:00:00 grep docker
```

I have looked into updating

I have tried updating my `iptables`

```
root@e898473347a2:/var/jenkins_home# apt-get install -y iptables
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
iptables is already the newest version (1.6.0+snapshot20161117-6).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

I have verified that I am `root` and the directories are owned by `root`.

```
root@e898473347a2:/var/jenkins_home# whoami
root
```

I have tried to research where to post this. Please tell me if this needs to be moved somewhere else. I will kindly move this if this doesn't classify as "programming".

Comment: check this up https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/overlayfs-driver/#configure-docker-with-the-overlay-or-overlay2-storage-driver

Comment: Checking it out.

Comment: have you solved your issue?

Comment: @Psychozoic Yeah. This is 3 years old too. Glad I got passed this by now lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to do Docker in Docker (DinD). It requires some hacks and changing the storage driver (you can't do overlay on overlay). See the `Dockerfile` and entrypoint script at https://github.com/docker-library/docker/tree/a73d96e731e2dd5d6822c99a9af4dcbfbbedb2be/19.03/dind for more information. It has information on where it gets the `dind` script and the necessary entrypoint changes to run `dockerd`.

However, there are official `dind` tagged images on Docker Hub that you may be better off building from. See https://hub.docker.com/_/docker/. You could just use image `docker:17.05.0-dind` or base your image off of it if you need customizations.

Comment: offical dind is cool, but not debain :(
ps. github is not working anymore...